# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <module_name> although module was installed

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run server for my django app, and I've used TinyMCE editor for admin panel. Although I've installed it with command `pip3 install django-tinymce` application returns me such error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce'
```

Comment: How are you running Django? What command are you running?

Comment: And the interesting part of situation is that, this app works well when I'm running server via PyCharm, but now I want to use VS Code, and getting such error.

Comment: @IainShelvington ```python3 manage.py runserver```

Comment: And when you run `python3 -m pip freeze` - do you see django-tinymce in the output?

Comment: @IainShelvington ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed```

Comment: Not sure which interpreter `pip3` is installing packages for. You need to run `python3 ensurepip`, then install packages using `python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: @IainShelvington the command ```pip3 freeze``` returns me all of modules, like:

```django-countries==5.5
django-tinymce==2.8.0
numpy==1.13.3
six==1.13.0```

Comment: are you added 'tinymce'  in INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: @MahrezBenHamad, yes, of course. This application works without any problem when I run server via PyCharm. But now I should use VS Code, and this problem is a real barrier for me.

Comment: do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: @MahrezBenHamad I've installed venv again, but didn't solve my problem. Again the same error ...

Comment: Try, to run python manage.py makemigrations
then
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial

Comment: Adding django-tinymce to requirements.txt and re-deploying may help